# How do I call afterclose in fancybox3 without initialization?

Tags: fancybox-3

In [fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) there is no need to initialize the fancybox through javascript. It is enough to set html attribute `data-fancybox=""` to an anchor to make it open as fancybox.

OK! now I want to call a function on **afterclose** but I don't know how to do that when I have no initialization function? The documentation suggests the method below but it is only suitable for methods with initialization:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        //Something;
    }
});
```

and this is my sample html link which opens a fancybox with no extra javascript:

```
<a data-fancybox="" href="../">open fancybox</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want customize, then either initialize with settings, change defaults or set options using `data-options` attribute.